# Boost Spirit QI issues with strings and skipping

Tags: c++, string, attributes, boost-spirit, skip

So I've begun playing with the Boost Spirit library and its absolutely amazing! But along the way i have ran into many errors - many on my behalf for not fully reading the documentation.. But after going through as much as I could find, i am stumped on attributes - strings in regards to skipping.

At the moment I'd like to detect an ASM alike label and print it in a console like so:

```
    Identifier = qi::lexeme[qi::alpha >> (*qi::alnum | qi::lit("_"))]
    Label      = Identifier >> ":"
    Syntax     = Label[phx::bind(&Grammar::print, this, qi::_1)];
```

where phx::bind calls a simple print string function to cout. The rules are defined like so:

```
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> Identifier;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> Label;
    qi::rule<Iterator,                ascii::space_type> Syntax;
```

Which works BUT the problem is, I don't want the skipper to skip between the Identifier and the ":" literal.

I have tried:

```
    Label = qi::lexeme [Identifier >> ":"]
    Label = qi::no_skip[.................]
    etc
```

But i receive error messages such as converting to parameter 4 - cannot convert unused_skipper<..> to char_class<..> which makes some sense. I also tried removing the skipper type on the rule definition which didn't work. I then tried mixing it up and making some rules attributes strings whilst others not, - and converting them to strings using as_string - worked, but output was empty. So here I am. stumped.

Is there something I'm not understanding about attribute propagation? Or perhaps something about attributes in general. Maybe even a method to return a string from a non-skipped sequence?

Would someone please be able to enlighten me on my errors? & Any future tips on attributes?

Many Thanks, Adam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lexeme solution does work.

The `no_skip` and `lexeme` directive require that the contained parsers don't use a skipper, so you need to change `Identifier` into

```
qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> Identifier;
```

Incidentally, then `lexeme` inside it becomes redundant:

```
qi::rule<It, std::string()                > Identifier = qi::alpha >> *(qi::alnum | qi::char_("_"));
qi::rule<It, std::string(), qi::space_type> Label      = qi::lexeme [ Identifier >> ':' ];
qi::rule<It,                qi::space_type> Syntax     = Label [ handle_label_(qi::_1) ];
```

In fact you can further reduce it (by relying on pre-skipping in the `Syntax` rule):

```
static const rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string()> 
    Identifier = alpha >> *(alnum | char_("_")),
    Label      = Identifier >> ':';
```

A full test program: See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e1aabd3b5541343)**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/phoenix/function/adapt_function.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

void handle_label(std::string const& s) { std::cout << "Parsed label '" << s << ":'\n"; }
BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(void, handle_label_, handle_label, 1)

bool using_lexeme(std::string const& input)
{
    using namespace qi;
    static const rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string()> 
        Identifier = alpha >> *(alnum | char_("_")),
        Label      = Identifier >> ':';

    auto f(input.begin()), l(input.end());
    return phrase_parse(f, l, Label [ handle_label_(_1) ], space);
}

int main()
{
    assert( using_lexeme("some_id:"));
    assert( using_lexeme("some_id: "));
    assert( using_lexeme(" some_id:"));
    assert(!using_lexeme("some_id :"));
}
```

---

#### Two further notes:

- `no_skip` doesn't pre-skip either (`lexeme` means more like "keep together"). Try the difference and see how the third test case would fail
- Your use of `lit('_')` would prevent underscores from being appended to the string attribute.

Comment: I've written more about skippers previously: answer to ["Boost spirit skipper issues"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)

Comment: Brilliant! This was one of my previous attempts but it failed. What happened? Well I copied your code into a new application and ran it, to which  it still didn't work(as my previous attempt didn't). So now knowing the code is correct i read back through my code to find an error in the base_type - where the template was asking for a qi::space and I was giving it a qi::ascii::space - causing it to fail). But It's all resolved now.

Thank You so much sehe - I pretty much live of all of your example online :)  Sehe-The god of Boost Spirit!

Thanks Again, Adam.